# Can't connect to any networks; no shell commands work; can't flush DNS cache

Tags: networking, windows-10, dns

I'm using windows 10 64 bit. I can't connect to the internet. I just keep getting "Dns_probe_finished_nxdomain" on Chrome.

I've tried running windows troubleshooter and it says "Troubleshooting can't identify the problem."

I've set my ipv4 DNS addresses to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.

I've restarted my computer.

I've done `/ipconfig release` and `/ipconfig renew`.

I tried `ipconfig /flushdns` and all it says is "Windows IP Configuration" and it's been stuck like that for ten minutes.

I tried opening Windows Services to manually restart the DNS Client but the options to do that are all greyed out-- a little Googling suggests that might be intentional for windows 10.

I've tried `net stop dnscache` in command prompt and it says "The service is not responding to the control function".

I know it's my laptop and not my internet because my phone works fine connected to the same network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I've tried running windows troubleshooter and it says "Troubleshooting can't identify the problem."

Try the following (running the commands in the order specified).

- Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

  `netsh int ip reset reset.log`
- Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

  `netsh advfirewall reset`
- Flush DNS resolver cache:

  `ipconfig /flushdns`
- Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

  `ipconfig /registerdns`
- Flush routing table (reboot required):

  `route /f`